# Cannot use format_args! due to temporary value is freed at the end of this statement

Tags: rust

I'm trying to construct my own custom [LogRecord](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.6/log/struct.Record.html) and pass it into the [log](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.6/log/) crate.

```rust
use log::RecordBuilder;

fn main() {
    let msg = format_args!("Completed: {}, Elapsed={:?}", "blah", 20);
    //let msg = format_args!("This is OK");
    let mut builder = RecordBuilder::new();
    let _log_rec = builder
        .args(msg)
        .build();
}
```

I'm running into a temporary lifetime problem with the call to the [args](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.6/log/struct.RecordBuilder.html#method.args) method. The error is

```
 --> src/main.rs:4:28
  |
4 |     let msg = format_args!("Completed: {}, Elapsed={:?}", "blah", 20);
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                            |
  |                            creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
...
8 |         .args(msg)
  |               --- borrow later used here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

Normally this would be an easy fix - just put the temporary into a local variable. In this case though, I don't understand how to fix it, since I've got everything I can think of into local variables already (and is why I don't think this question is a duplicate of the others). It seems to be something particular to the `format_args!` macro.

Interestingly, the problem goes away if you don't use any `{}` placeholders in the call to `format_args!()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`format_args!` is expected to be invoked exactly where the returned value will be used.

```rust
let mut builder = RecordBuilder::new();
let _log_rec = builder
    .args(format_args!("Completed: {}, Elapsed={:?}", "blah", 20))
    .build();
```

This is because, as how it's implemented, the macro expands into (among other constructs) a sequence of narrowly scoped values for each of the given parameters, and the [`Arguments`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html) value is created with only a large enough lifetime to capture them.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It did not work when I applied it to my actual code rather than this minimum-repro code, however I was able to get it to work by applying the 'inline the call' technique again. I will edit the question to show the actual solution as others mmay find it useful, especially if they are beginners.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround that uses closure.

```
(|msg: std::fmt::Arguments| {
    // use `msg` here...
})(format_args!("literal string"));
```

Thanks to [`std::fmt::Arguments::as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html#method.as_str), the advantage of using the workaround is that you can convert `std::fmt::Arguments` to `Cow<str>` on the spot (e.g. inside a macro) to avoid allocations for literal strings.

```
(|msg: std::fmt::Arguments| {
    let msg: Cow<str> = match msg.as_str() {
        Some(literal) => literal.into(), // no format arguments, so it is a `&'static str`
        None => msg.to_string().into(),
    };

    // use `msg` here...
})(format_args!("literal string"));
```

If you get blamed by `clippy`, just put `#[allow(clippy::redundant_closure_call)]` on the closure.

```
#[allow(clippy::redundant_closure_call)]
(|msg: std::fmt::Arguments| {
    let msg: Cow<str> = match msg.as_str() {
        Some(literal) => literal.into(), // no format arguments, so it is a `&'static str`
        None => msg.to_string().into(),
    };

    // use `msg` here...
})(format_args!("literal string"));
```

Answer (score 2):

OP's solution<sup><sup>1</sup>:</sup>

> [The solution from E_net4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56304571/2766908) is correct. It did not work immediately in my actual code, which was:
>
> ```rust
> impl Drop for ExecutionTimer2 {
>     fn drop(&mut self) {
>         let elapsed = self.start_time.elapsed();
>
>         let mut builder = RecordBuilder::new();
>         let log_rec = builder
>             .level(Level::Debug)
>             .target("ExecutionTimer")
>             .file(Some(self.file))
>             .module_path(Some(self.module_path))
>             .line(Some(self.line))
>             .args(format_args!(
>                 "Completed: {}, Elapsed={:?}",
>                 self.name, elapsed
>             ))
>             .build();
>
>         let logger = log::logger();
>         logger.log(&log_rec);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> but I applied the 'inlining' technique again to come up with this code, which does compile:
>
> ```rust
> impl Drop for ExecutionTimer2 {
>     fn drop(&mut self) {
>         let elapsed = self.start_time.elapsed();
>         let mut builder = RecordBuilder::new();
>         let logger = log::logger();
>
>         logger.log(
>             &builder
>                 .level(Level::Debug)
>                 .target("ExecutionTimer")
>                 .file(Some(self.file))
>                 .module_path(Some(self.module_path))
>                 .line(Some(self.line))
>                 .args(format_args!(
>                     "Completed: {}, Elapsed={:?}",
>                     self.name, elapsed
>                 ))
>                 .build(),
>         );
>     }
> }
> ```

---

<sub>1 As it was edited into the question it had to be removed because answers don't belong in questions.</sub>

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have come up with that...