# Temporary value dropped while borrowed when printing `format_args!`

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

(There are a million questions with a similar title but I think this one is distinct from them all.)

Rust version: 1.69.0.

The following works as expected:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{}", format_args!("hello {}", "world"));
}
```

But the borrow checker prevents the following code from compiling.

```rust
fn main() {
    let args = format_args!("hello {}", "world");
    println!("{}", args);
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:2:16
  |
2 |     let args = format_args!("hello {}", "world");
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                |
  |                creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
3 |     println!("{}", args);
  |                    ---- borrow later used here
  |
  = note: this error originates in the macro `format_args` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
  |
2 ~     let binding = format_args!("hello {}", "world");
3 ~     let args = binding;
  |
```

I can't see any violations of Rust’s borrow rules — everything is in scope, bound to a variable, not dropped prematurely, etc., as far as I can tell. [`fmt::Arguments<'a>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html) has a lifetime parameter but it's not clear what data it's trying to hold onto that is being dropped. Also, the help message is clearly bogus (`args` is exactly as long lived as `binding` would be!).

Comment: good question, format_args is a compiler built-in so... hard to answer, guess well, you can't do that.

Comment: I don't believe it's a duplicate, since here you ask about general rule that should work, and the other is about how to get around this limitation

Comment: I think it's close enough to close. Pretty odd to close my own question and have someone else reopen it!

Comment: question on SO are common resource once you posted a question it's become public resource see license of SO. You are just original author of the question. and so yes your own question can become reopen without your consent :p duplicate is about answer, not the question, the answer in the other question doesn't really answer your good question that is "wtf is this not compiling ?" other is "how to fix my code ?" that very related but not duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an known issue see [#92698](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/92698). For now we can't do that in Rust.

Related: [Cannot use format_args! due to temporary value is freed at the end of this statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304313/cannot-use-format-args-due-to-temporary-value-is-freed-at-the-end-of-this-state)

Comment: From one of the comments by @m-ou-se: *"format_args's expansion includes temporaries whose lifetimes need to be extended. We currently don't have a flexible way to do that."*